# Как правильно сверстать данный блок

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, scss

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сверстать данный title новичку? Думал обернуть каждое слово в отдельный div и через margin прописать, но для адаптива это не лучшее решение думаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: rgb(207, 159, 159);
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 2.7em;
}
.header > span:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: start;
}
.header > span:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: end;
}
.header > span:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>Предрейсовые и</span>
  <span>предсменные</span>
  <span>осмотры.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @russianBoy, если ответ удовлетворяет вашим требованиям, то можете отметить это, нажав слева от него на соответствующий значок, а если еще и понравился, то там же нажать на треугольник вверх. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Надо обернуть каждую строчку в отдельный , которые будут внутри флексбокса. Далее нужно просто присвоить нужным div-строчкам нужные свойства justify-content

Comment: То есть я задаю родительскому display flex а дочернему который мне надо сместить justify-content flex-end? Если такой ход мыслей, то так не работает